# Declare conformance to objective-c protocol with a category and implement it with another category

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

clang reports that `Test1(FooBar)` doesn't implement `foo` or `bar`, despite foo being implemented in `Test1(Foo)` and `bar` being implemented in `Test1`.  Since `Test1(Foo)`'s `@interface` exists above `Test1(FooBar)`'s, clang should see that `Test1(Foo)` implements `foo` and shouldn't require me to implement it in `Test1(FooBar)`.  Since `Test1` implements `bar`, clang shouldn't require me to implement it in `Test1(FooBar)`.

```
@interface Test1 : NSObject

- (void) bar;

@end

@interface Test1(Foo)

- (void) foo;

@end

@protocol FooBar <NSObject>

- (void) foo;
- (void) bar;

@end

@interface Test1(FooBar)<FooBar>

@end

@implementation Test1(Foo)

- (void) foo {
}

@end

@implementation Test1(FooBar)

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that this line:

```
@interface Test1(FooBar)<FooBar>
```

can be interpreted in plain english as "The *category* FooBar on class Test1 should implement protocol FooBar".  In other words, the protocol applies to the category, not the class.

Comment: Categories are effectively folded into the class at runtime;  there is no difference between category and class, really (In fact, there is no means of identifying categories by name at runtime -- the most you can do is grub through the method lists to note that methods from a category are typically stored in a different linked list than the main class's methods).  During compile time, there is still meaning to a category and, thus, I would expect this to imply that the implementation of `Test1(FooBar)<FooBar>` must implement the contract of `<FooBar>` to keep the compiler quiet.

Comment: @bbum Thanks for the explanation. I feel like the compiler should be smarter about this and filed a radar. If you'd change this comment to an answer, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: It seems like what you're trying to achieve is inheritance among categories, which as a concept does not exist in objective-c regardless of how it is achieved during runtime.